# System is no longer outputting UTF-8 characters

Tags: stdout, output, special-characters, tree

I just had an issue with my server where it responded incredibly slowly, so I forced it to reboot over SSH. When I connected back, I found out my system no longer outputs certain characters correctly.

Example: I use the `tree` command a lot to quickly see how a directory is structured and what's inside of it, when I use it on another system I'll get this output:

```
root@hostname:/tmp# tree
.
└── test
    ├── bar
    │   ├── bar
    │   ├── baz
    │   └── foo
    └── foo

2 directories, 4 files
```

However if I now do it on my system, I get the following:

```
root@hostname:/tmp# tree
.
ΓööΓöÇΓöÇ test
    Γö£ΓöÇΓöÇ bar
    Γöé┬á┬á Γö£ΓöÇΓöÇ bar
    Γöé┬á┬á Γö£ΓöÇΓöÇ baz
    Γöé┬á┬á ΓööΓöÇΓöÇ foo
    ΓööΓöÇΓöÇ foo

2 directories, 4 files
```

Is there any way of finding out how this happened? And how could I restore it?

**Edit**

using `LC_ALL=C tree` outputs the following:

```
root@hostname:/tmp# LC_ALL=C tree
.
`-- test
    |-- bar
    |   |-- bar
    |   |-- baz
    |   `-- foo
    `-- foo

2 directories, 4 files
```

Using `locale` outputs the following:

```
root@hostname:/tmp# locale
LANG=en_GB.utf8
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="en_GB.utf8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_GB.utf8"
LC_TIME="en_GB.utf8"
LC_COLLATE="en_GB.utf8"
LC_MONETARY="en_GB.utf8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_GB.utf8"
LC_PAPER="en_GB.utf8"
LC_NAME="en_GB.utf8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_GB.utf8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_GB.utf8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_GB.utf8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_GB.utf8"
LC_ALL=en_GB.utf8
```

Comment: Do `LC_ALL=C tree`

Comment: @heemayl It now outputs a simillar structure, but not the same as it was before

Comment: Meaning? Please add that to your answer along with the output of `locale`

Comment: @heemayl Updated question

Comment: Which terminal emulator are you using?  XTerm?  Gnome Terminal?  PuTTY?  Something else?

Answer (score 4):

The information in the question is sketchy.  However, the sample output shows more characters in the mis-encoded tree than one would expect.  Likely what's happening is that `tree` is running in an environment where it can send UTF-8.  For the graphic characters used, that's 3 bytes per special character.  On one side (local or remote doesn't matter), OP is using something which *re-encodes* those into UTF-8, increasing the number of bytes (since each of the bytes in the output of `tree` will be in the range 128-255).

For instance, if OP is running in [xterm](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/xterm.html) (using [luit](http://invisible-island.net/luit/luit.html)), and has confused things by (in effect) telling luit that the actual encoding is `en_GB`, it will translate each of those 128-255 values into 2-3 bytes ("back" into UTF-8).

By the way, *bash* is not relevant to the question, because it is *tree* (a distinct utility) which writes the text.

Answer (score 0):

using LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8 makes tree chars right but mucks up sort

changing back to LC_ALL=C so sort works right

never had sort & char issues until Mint Mate 20.1, it all used to work

Comment: This won't fix the data that was copied about 6 years ago (in the original question). You are trying to "fix" commands such as tree or ls by pretending to be using a different country code or collating sequence. Fix the data, not the locale.